# Amplify GraphQl stopped working for no apparent reason

Tags: graphql, amazon-dynamodb, aws-amplify

I developed my first app using AWS Amplify and everything was working well. But now I opened the app after about a week without opening and the only thing that it's working is the login. But my graphql API it's simply not working anymore, I can't mutate or query data.

If I go to the panel of my DynamoDB I can mutate and query data without a problem, so that makes me think problem is the graphql API.

What is more surprising to me is that I didn't find more people having this issue and/or documentation to solve this problem.

Hopefully somebody knows what might be the problem. Thanks

Comment: Having information that allows one to help diagnose your issue would be beneficial.

Comment: I am having this exact same issue. Please share how you fixed it